# Zeta Function and Wolfram Alpha

Tags: complex-analysis

Why the formula 
$$
\zeta(s)\Gamma(s)=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
is not applicable for $\operatorname{Re}(s)<1$ though we can derive this for any $s$ such that $\operatorname{Re}(s)>1$?

If the formula is invalid and the integral and the gamma function is undefined, then why Wolfram Alpha gives specific value for $$
\zeta(s)\times\frac{\Gamma(s)}{\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1}\,\mathrm{d}x}
$$
for $s$ such that $\operatorname{Re}(s)<1$.
Does the expression $$
\zeta(s)\Gamma(s)/\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$ has the value equals to 1 always?

Comment: Why is there an image of Einstein? What is the relation to the zeta function?

Comment: Sorry by mistake I uploaded his image.

Comment: "the gamma function is unfriend" ???

Comment: For $\Re(s) > 1$ and by analytic continuation for $\Re(s) > -1$ you'll have $\zeta(s)\Gamma(s)-\frac{1}{s-1}+\frac{1}{2s} = \int_0^\infty x^{s-2}(\frac{x}{e^x-1}-(1-\frac{x}{2})1_{x < 1})\,\mathrm{d}x$ where $1-\frac{x}{2}+O(x^2)$ is the Taylor approximation of $\frac{x}{e^x-1}$ which is smooth and analytic at $x=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Near $x=0$, the integrand
$$
\frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1}\sim x^{s-2}
$$
so is not Lebesgue/absolutely integrable on $[0,\varepsilon]$ if $\operatorname{Re}s\leq 1$.